# ansible inventory groups using jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, inventory

```
devices:
  children:
    abcgroup:
      children:
        xyzgroup:
          children:
            group1:
              hosts:
                device509:
                  ansible_ssh_host: 1.1.1.1
                device510:
                  ansible_ssh_host: 2.2.2.2
            group2:
              hosts:
                devcice609:
                  ansible_ssh_host: 3.3.3.3
                device610:
                  ansible_ssh_host: 4.4.4.4
        defgroup:
          hosts:
            device0508:
                ansible_ssh_host: 30.30.30.30
            device0608:
                ansible_ssh_host: 31.31.31.31
```

my jinja2 template

```
peer-keepalive destination {% if 'group1' in group_names %}{{ansible_ssh_host[1]}} source {{ansible_ssh_host}} {% endif %}

peer-keepalive destination {% if 'group2' in group_names %}{{ansible_ssh_host[1]}} source {{ansible_ssh_host}} {% endif %}
```

wanted output or desired output

```
on device509 i should get below output
peer-keepalive destination 2.2.2.2 source 1.1.1.1

on device510 i should get below output
peer-keepalive destination 1.1.1.1 source 2.2.2.2

on device609 i should get below output
peer-keepalive destination 4.4.4.4 source 3.3.3.3

on device610 i should get below output
peer-keepalive destination 3.3.3.3 source 4.4.4.4
```

output i am getting on each device is below, my jinja2 template is wrong i am getting dot (.)

```
on device509 i get below
peer-keepalive destination . source 1.1.1.1 

device510 i get below
peer-keepalive destination . source 2.2.2.2 

on device609 i get below
peer-keepalive destination . source 3.3.3.3 

device610 i get below
peer-keepalive destination . source 4.4.4.4
```

how to fix this

Comment: If you want the ip from an other host, why are you asking for the second character of the current host IP? What you get is exactly what you asked for => `.` Your requirement is actually not clear at all. For the source, it's quite easy: you want to use the current host IP. But how do you get the destination IP?

Comment: @Zeitounator device509 and device510 is a pair, on device509 destination ip should be device510 ip and on device510 destination ip should be device 509 ip. Wanted output is differyfrom what i am getting, looks like my jinja2 template is wrong , i am not sure how to get ‘wanted output’

Comment: Before you even think about a template, you have IMO a design problem. How do you decide which devices are in a pair? Because they are in the same group? What happens if suddenly the group contains 3 hosts? Are you aware that e.g. `device509` belongs to already 5 groups in your inventory? How will you make the difference between `group1` and `device`? My 2 cent: if you are designing pairs, simply add a `network_peer: deviceXXX` variable for each device. While running on any device, you can then access any value on the peer in the `hostvars[network_peer]` dictionnary.

Comment: @Zeitounator thank you for your suggestion, i have posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
peer-keepalive destination {{ hostvars[groups['group1'][1]].ansible_ssh_host }} source {{ hostvars[groups['group1'][0]].ansible_ssh_host }}

peer-keepalive destination {{ hostvars[groups['group1'][0]].ansible_ssh_host }} source {{ hostvars[groups['group1'][1]].ansible_ssh_host }}
```

same thing for group2